# Calculate the limit: $ \lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}}{x^4+y^4}}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> Calculate the limit:
> $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}}{x^4+y^4}}
> $$

I tried to change to polar coordinates like that:
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}}{x^4+y^4}} &=
\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}}{(x^2+y^2)^2-2x^2y^2}}\\
&=\lim\limits_{r\to0}{\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}}}{r^4(1-2\cos^2\theta \sin^2\theta)}}\\
\end{align*}
and I'm not sure how to continue from this point.

Thank you!

Comment: If you show that $\displaystyle \lim_{r \to 0} \dfrac{e^{-1/r^2}}{r^4} = 0$, you are done. It is also advisable to establish that $1- 2 \cos^2 \theta \sin^2 \theta \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** For now, *suppose that the limit exists* and is equal to $L$. Then,
$$L = \lim\limits_{r\to0}{\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}}}{r^4(1-2\cos^2\theta \sin^2\theta)}}$$
Take $\theta = \frac\pi 2$ first. Then, $$L = \lim\limits_{r\to0}{\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}}}{r^4}}$$
Now, take $\theta = \frac\pi 4$. Then,
$$L = \lim\limits_{r\to0}{\frac{2e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}}}{r^4}} = 2L \implies L =  0$$
So, **if the limit exists**, it must be equal to $0$.

---

**Proof of Existence.**

> Observe that $$\frac{e^{-1/r^2}}{r^4(\sin^4\theta+\cos^4\theta)} \leq \frac{2}{r^4e^{1/r^2}}$$

> Now, since $r^5e^{1/r^2}\to \infty$ as $r\to 0^+$, there is $\delta'>0$ such that $$0<r<\delta' \implies r^5e^{1/r^2} > 2 \implies \frac{2}{r^4e^{1/r^2}} < r$$

> Finally, choose $\delta = \min\{\delta',\epsilon\}$ to conclude that $$0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta \implies 0 < r < \delta \implies \left|{\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}}{x^4+y^4}}\right|<\epsilon$$

Comment: Why did you feel the need to try two values of $theta$? Your conclusion would be the same if you only tried one.

Comment: I use that to conclude $L = 0$. See the computation. @PierreCarre

Comment: You don't need to try two values of $\theta$, one is enough.

Comment: @PierreCarre Using two values, I am able to show $2L = L$, which implies $L = 0$. How do you reproduce this argument with just one value?

Comment: If the limit exists, it is independent of $\theta$. So, just pick a value for $\theta$ and compute the limit when $r \to 0$... Why are you avoiding the calculation of a 1d limit? Or better yet, why don't you just see that the $\theta$ part is not zero and the limit in $r$ is zero? This way you show existence without further delay.

Comment: @PierreCarre Makes sense. I'm avoiding the calculation because picking two values (which is also fine) gives me the answer right away! :)

Comment: Not right away, because you still need to show existence... If you compute the limit, existence follows.

Comment: No, existence does not follow. Just because the limit exists along a *particular value* of $\theta$, does not mean that it exists for all $\theta\in [0, 2\pi)$. @PierreCarre

Comment: It does follow... this is quite standard. If the limit when $r\to 0$ is the same for all $\theta$, the 2d limit exists. This is not the same as the directional limits.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x^{4}+y^{4} \geq \frac  1 2 ({x^{2}+y^{2}})^{2}$. Now use polar coordinates to see that the limit is $0$.

This allows you to get rid of $\theta$. You will also need the fact that $t^{4}e^{-t} \to 0$ as $ t \to \infty$ (Take $t=\frac  1r$). This fact is proved using L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: @trancelocation Yes, that is what I wanted to say. Thanks fo the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Since $1-2\cos^2 \theta \sin^2 \theta \ne 0$ the limit in polar coordinates becomes
$$
\frac{1}{1-2\cos^2 \theta \sin^2 \theta}\cdot \lim_{r\to 0}\dfrac{e^{-1/r^2}}{r^4}=0, \quad \forall \theta \in[0,2\pi)
$$

This shows that the original limit is zero.